# How to determine most curvature points of a graph in python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a figure that I get contour lines from a picture of face use by opencv (image below). I need to determine most curvature points of this contour in python (in the image, I need to define the red dots on right of the red line). How can I do it ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just find contour and compute curvature then find maximums: [curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature)

This article also may be useful: [article](http://www.morethantechnical.com/2012/12/07/resampling-smoothing-and-interest-points-of-curves-via-css-in-opencv-w-code/)